# How to know when TextField in a WKWebView is Tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, webkit, wkwebview

In this Apple [doc about Keyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), the first sentence says:

> When users touch a text field, a text view, or a **field in a web view**,
> the system displays a keyboard.

Are there any methods or KVO observers to know when a user **starts/stops typing** in a **field in WKWebView**?

For example, when interacting with a regular UITextField, if I want to know when a user starts and stops typing, these two methods are available, but WKWebView doesn't have anything like these

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

}
```

I don't need the keyboardWillShow/Hide notifications. I need some delegate methods or a KVO for the textFields **specific to WKWebView**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately WKWebView does't have delegate methods that gets called when web form inputs are triggered.